# Tomcat won't access hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter using intellij

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir, dstu2-fhir

I am trying to understand how the fhir works so i read the documentation and in the documentation they recommended me to deploy fhir server from https://github.com/hapifhir/hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter. So first I imported the project in intellij and then configured Tomcat server and the database and finally deployed it and this is what I got

```
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.304 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardWrapperValve[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi].StandardWrapper[jsp]]] to [INITIALIZING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.304 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardWrapperValve[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi].StandardWrapper[jsp]]] to [INITIALIZED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.304 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardWrapperValve[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi].StandardWrapper[jsp]]] to [STARTING_PREP]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.304 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardWrapperValve[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi].StandardWrapper[jsp]]] to [STARTING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.304 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardWrapperValve[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi].StandardWrapper[jsp]]] to [STARTED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.304 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardPipeline[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi].StandardWrapper[jsp]]] to [STARTING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.304 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardPipeline[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi].StandardWrapper[jsp]]] to [STARTED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.304 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi].StandardWrapper[jsp]] to [STARTING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.304 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi].StandardWrapper[jsp]] to [STARTED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.306 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@6c8c317a] to [INITIALIZING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.307 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@6c8c317a] to [INITIALIZED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.307 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@6c8c317a] to [STARTING_PREP]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.307 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@6c8c317a] to [STARTING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.307 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@6c8c317a] to [STARTED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.311 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@2efc28f9] to [INITIALIZING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.311 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@2efc28f9] to [INITIALIZED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.311 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@2efc28f9] to [STARTING_PREP]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.312 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@2efc28f9] to [STARTING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.312 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@2efc28f9] to [STARTED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.312 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@6d455594] to [INITIALIZING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.313 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@6d455594] to [INITIALIZED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.313 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@6d455594] to [STARTING_PREP]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.313 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@6d455594] to [STARTING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.313 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@6d455594] to [STARTED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.317 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@bcba6d2] to [INITIALIZING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.317 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@bcba6d2] to [INITIALIZED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.317 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@bcba6d2] to [STARTING_PREP]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.317 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@bcba6d2] to [STARTING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.317 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@bcba6d2] to [STARTED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.320 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@5e6cc3b4] to [INITIALIZING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.320 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@5e6cc3b4] to [INITIALIZED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.320 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@5e6cc3b4] to [STARTING_PREP]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.320 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@5e6cc3b4] to [STARTING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.320 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@5e6cc3b4] to [STARTED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.330 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@2579af15] to [INITIALIZING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.330 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@2579af15] to [INITIALIZED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.330 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@2579af15] to [STARTING_PREP]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.330 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@2579af15] to [STARTING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.331 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@2579af15] to [STARTED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.336 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@7a19108b] to [INITIALIZING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.336 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@7a19108b] to [INITIALIZED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.336 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@7a19108b] to [STARTING_PREP]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.336 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@7a19108b] to [STARTING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.336 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@7a19108b] to [STARTED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.337 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@bad542b] to [INITIALIZING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.337 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@bad542b] to [INITIALIZED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.337 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@bad542b] to [STARTING_PREP]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.337 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@bad542b] to [STARTING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.337 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@bad542b] to [STARTED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.341 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@30f54c84] to [INITIALIZING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.341 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@30f54c84] to [INITIALIZED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.341 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@30f54c84] to [STARTING_PREP]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.341 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@30f54c84] to [STARTING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.342 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@30f54c84] to [STARTED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.343 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@2c62401d] to [INITIALIZING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.343 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@2c62401d] to [INITIALIZED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.343 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@2c62401d] to [STARTING_PREP]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.343 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@2c62401d] to [STARTING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.343 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@2c62401d] to [STARTED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.351 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@4e695b7e] to [INITIALIZING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.351 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@4e695b7e] to [INITIALIZED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.351 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@4e695b7e] to [STARTING_PREP]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.351 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@4e695b7e] to [STARTING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.351 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@4e695b7e] to [STARTED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.354 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@6d6c1cd7] to [INITIALIZING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.354 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@6d6c1cd7] to [INITIALIZED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.355 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@6d6c1cd7] to [STARTING_PREP]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.355 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@6d6c1cd7] to [STARTING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.355 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@6d6c1cd7] to [STARTED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.362 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl@49e41096] to [INITIALIZING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.363 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl@49e41096] to [INITIALIZED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.363 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl@49e41096] to [STARTING_PREP]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.363 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl@49e41096] to [STARTING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.363 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl@49e41096] to [STARTED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.363 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardPipeline[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi]]] to [INITIALIZING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.363 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardPipeline[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi]]] to [INITIALIZED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.363 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardPipeline[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi]]] to [STARTING_PREP]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.363 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi]]] to [INITIALIZING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.363 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi]]] to [INITIALIZED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.363 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi]]] to [STARTING_PREP]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.363 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi]]] to [STARTING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.363 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi]]] to [STARTED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.363 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardContextValve[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi]]] to [INITIALIZING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.364 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardContextValve[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi]]] to [INITIALIZED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.364 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardContextValve[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi]]] to [STARTING_PREP]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.364 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardContextValve[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi]]] to [STARTING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.364 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardContextValve[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi]]] to [STARTED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.364 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardPipeline[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi]]] to [STARTING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.364 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardPipeline[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi]]] to [STARTED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.915 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.920 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardManager[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi]]] to [INITIALIZING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.920 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardManager[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi]]] to [INITIALIZED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.921 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardManager[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi]]] to [STARTING_PREP]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.921 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.util.StandardSessionIdGenerator@29ff4d70] to [INITIALIZING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.921 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.util.StandardSessionIdGenerator@29ff4d70] to [INITIALIZED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.921 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.util.StandardSessionIdGenerator@29ff4d70] to [STARTING_PREP]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.921 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.util.StandardSessionIdGenerator@29ff4d70] to [STARTING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.921 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.util.StandardSessionIdGenerator@29ff4d70] to [STARTED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.921 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardManager[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi]]] to [STARTING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.921 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardManager[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi]]] to [STARTED]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.938 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi]] to [STARTING]
    02-Apr-2023 18:26:33.938 FINE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hapi]] to [STARTED]
    [2023-04-02 06:26:33,946] Artifact hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter:war: Artifact is deployed successfully
    [2023-04-02 06:26:33,946] Artifact hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter:war: Deploy took 26,647 milliseconds
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by changing the version from tomcat 10.1 to tomcat 9.
So the issue was because of incompatibility of tomcat version with fhir server.